# In VBA excel I have a userform with a Listbox of items, how to prevent the user from accidently selecting items as they click into the cell?

Tags: excel, vba

What I want to allow is the ability for a user to select a cell for a particular column and then for this to enable a pop-up menu and for them to make a selection. I was able to do this using the following link: http://www.vlsiip.com/exceltips.html

But because the initial behavior (single select) was triggering the userform upon clicking once or hitting the diagonal pad into it, and also not allowing the user to select it again  after confirming an initial selection, I instead opted for the double-click approach in vba like so:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
```

This worked, now I think it's more intuitive to the user -- they can click the cell twice and this triggers the menu of options, they then make a selection, hit OK and it populates the cell. And they can also double-click again while the cell is still highlighted and make any updates they wish. The problem I am facing is, since there are a lot of options in the userform and since I want to make the userform big -- when a user double-clicks the cell it automatically highlights items from the list where the users mouse is clicking at. So I think its triggered by the users mouse being in the same location of the options in the listbox. So my question is, is there a workaround here? I like the functionality of double-click so far, but am having the unintended consequence of options being accidentally clicked. This was also verified when I trimmed the list of items down to 3, it no longer had options selected, but if I reach like 15 items the userform can get accidentally clicked if the options are in the same region of where the current cell is at.

It looks similar like this but much bigger and many more options:

[image]

Comment: In your screenshot the cell and list don’t overlap though, so how would the user accidentally select something when triggering the userform?

Comment: @TimWilliams That was an example from the link provided. In the actual code the userform is much bigger.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. It seems you control the selection in the list and  transfer to the sheet very well. Please also show any code you have used for this (we are not happy to look at other sites for code that you should include in your question.

Comment: I just saw your response to @Tim. In essence, you should provide the code that reproduces your problem, not something, somewhere, which isn't actually producing the error you ask about.

Comment: Hey all, figured it out. Just added a slight delay and this resolved this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to solve this by creating a slight delay in the userform code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
On Error resume Next
Me.ListBox2.Clear

Me.ListBox2.Enabled = False

For Each element In gCountryListArr
    Me.ListBox2.AddItem element
Next element

UserForm_initialize

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")

Me.ListBox2.Enabled = True

End Sub
```